# Les deux noms pour chaque point cardinal

Tags: choix-de-mot, étymologie

Quelquefois on entend

> « le nord, le sud, l'est, et l'ouest »,

et quelquefois

> « le septentrion, le midi, l'orient, et l'occident ».

Le premier ensemble est descendu du germanique commun et le second du latin, n'est-ce pas?  Pourquoi les deux ensembles et quelle est la distinction d'usage?

Comment: Also have a look at [ELU: How do you form the 'north' and 'south' versions of 'occident' and 'orient'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68008/16833), especially [that link](http://members.tripod.com/~gremio_fenix/trabalhos/orient_occident.html) from the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Au passage, il me semble que les points cardinaux prennent une majuscule quand ils sont des noms: _Le Nord_ (mais on peut écrire en minuscule quand c'est un adjectif comme _le pôle nord_)

Comment: On parle aussi de Ponant et de Levant.

Comment: @rds: Je crois que c'est la règle en anglais, quoique « the North Pole », mais je ne pense pas que les points cardinaux eux-mêmes prennent une majuscule en français si on ne nomme une certaine région par sa direction cardinale.

Comment: Vous pouvez ajouter le levant et le couchant (ponant), l'austral et le boréal, et pour les marins les sous-cardinaux noroît, nordet, suroît, sudet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Nord*, *sud*, *est*, *ouest* avec *nadir* et *zénith* sont des points cardinaux, ils indiquent une direction à partir d'un point sur le globe terrestre. Ils sont couramment utilisés pour indiquer une direction sur une carte. Ils apparaissent en particulier dans plusieurs expressions imagées :

- *ne pas perdre le nord* (conserver sa raison, poursuivre sa route sans erreur)
- *être à l'ouest* (familier pour dire que l'on a perdu la raison)
- *aller dans les pays du sud* (pour profiter du soleil)
- *le soleil se lève encore à l'est* (pour dire que rien n'a changé)

Les autres expressions désignent en général des régions plutôt que des directions :

- *septentrion* est vieilli et surtout usité en poésie ou en littérature.
- *midi* est particulier, il concerne aussi le milieu du jour (chacun voit midi à sa porte), mais lorsqu'il indique une direction, il indique le plus souvent le sud d'un pays : passer ses vacances dans le midi de la France.
- *orient* est plus complexe : lié à la religion, au mot orientation, il propose trois situations (franco centrées) :

  - le Proche-Orient, de l’Égypte à la Turquie,
  - le Moyen-Orient : les pays qui s'étendent jusqu'à l'Inde exclue
  - l'Extrême-Orient, dont la Chine est le symbole resté longtemps mystérieux.
- *occident* ajoute une valeur géopolitique.

Comment: Est-ce que "midi" est employé pour une autre région que le sud de la France? Je ne l'ai jamais lu ou entendu employé avec un autre pays ou région.

Comment: @Circeus Ayant peu voyagé, je l'ignore - mais c'est vrai qu'il ne peut s'agir que d'un pays de l'hémisphère nord.

Comment: @Circeus - Souvent, le Midi fait référence au sud-est de la France. Sinon on précise: "Midi Toulousain". D'autre part, en montagne il y a souvent des "Pic du Midi". Ils désignent les sommets qui sont dans la même direction que le soleil à l'heure de midi pour un village ou une vallée donnée.

Comment: Je ne l'ai jamais su, mais le mot _septentrion_ réfère au sept étoiles du Nord.

Comment: Je voudrais rajouter qu'en italien on utilise aussi "Mezzogiorno" pour le Sud. On dit que cela fait référence à la position du soleil à Midi qui, dans notre hémisphère, est au sud du Zenith.

Answer (score 5):

Il est vrai qu'à part la valeur géopolitique de *Orient* et *Occident*, ces termes sont beaucoup moins commun que les points géographiques. Toutefois, leur formes adjectivales sont employés plus communément (par ex. pour décrire l'aire de distribution d'une espèce): occidental, oriental, septentrional et méridional.